# Hudson job enable and disable while it is in queue

Tags: java, hudson

Can I disable the job while it is in que waiting for build. 
and 
 Can I delete my job from the que itself?

My Automation program is like this :

1. Check for the job if currently executing .
2. If not executing disable to job
3. Delete the repository directory(maven based project) for that particular job , where it downloaded   dependency jars.
4. update the job (source) contents from version controller.
5. Enable the job.

Example Scenario:

1. Currently the job is not executing ,
2. It is passed through Step 2 and disabled the job, but that job is in build queue.
3. Started executing deleting the dependency files.
   While executing step 3 , Build started from the queue and failed due to dependency not found and they are deleted from Step 3.

---

My Question is:

If the job is disabled and in build queue, will that job will be disabled or not ?
Will it be disabled from the next run?
In my scenario it is executing the job even it is disabled.

Comment: which framework have u used for that ..?/

Comment: What overall goal are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It is build automation tool. Get the contents(source) from version controller and update to the job  on periodic time intervals. (As i'm using clearcase I don't want to create multiple views since I've n number of jobs , so I avoided using clearcase hudson plugin's) . Yes for each job it has its own maven dependency repository

Comment: Hmmm...why not just use Hudson itself?

Comment: Infact my automation program creates the jobs for all the clearcase views categeorized by users. I can't use hudson GUI any more because I've so many views using at a certain point of time for those I've create jobs , If I use clearcase plugin , the plugin creates on more view corresponding to each job, A LOAD ON CLEARCASE. Anyways let me see currently it is under observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to actually disable a job. However, I found a way to check whether a job is in the build queue. Use the remote API, which gives you all the items currently in the build view. But I didn't find a way to get all information to generate the cancel link.

```
http://server:port/queue/api/xml
```